# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var id    = $('.getval_'+product_id+''+index+'').attr("id");
var value = "";

console.log(id);
//data that return by id
6059
s2id_6061
6122
s2id_8410

if (id.indexOf('s2id_') > 0) {
    value = $('.getval_'+product_id+''+index+'').select2('val');
}else{      
    value = $('.getval_'+product_id+''+index+'').val();
}
```

**Question:**
The code above is show that when the **ID** return by jquery, then it will show a list of data, so what I want is when the **ID** return, if the in front of **ID** don't have **s2id_** it will go else statement. But the code return an error which is **(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined)**

Comment: `+''`? This is not needed at any point in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check whether `id` itself is set, and there are two ways of going about this.

Either chain the `if (id.indexOf('s2id_') > 0)` condition inside an outer `if` condition that checks for `id`:

```
if (id) {
    if (id.indexOf('s2id_') > 0) {
        value = $('.getval_'+product_id+''+index+'').select2('val');
    }else{      
        value = $('.getval_'+product_id+''+index+'').val();
    }
}
```

Or check for **both** conditions with an **and** statement:

```
if (id && id.indexOf('s2id_') > 0) {
    value = $('.getval_'+product_id+''+index+'').select2('val');
}else{      
    value = $('.getval_'+product_id+''+index+'').val();
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: `if (&& id.indexOf('s2id_') > 0)` this should be  `if (id.indexOf('s2id_') > 0)`

Comment: It's important to check `id` as well -- if you check for it and it is not set, the `if` condition won't be triggered. If you don't check for `id` and it is not set, it will attempt to check for `id.indexOf()`, and will throw an error because `id` is undefined.

Comment: @ObsidianAge He means you have a typo in your first example? am not sure

Comment: @ObsidianAge  I mean you have an extra '&&' on your answer

Comment: Oh, I see. I did indeed. Was looking at the wrong one of the two examples ;) Well spotted!